# "Web to Case" Caseses are not showing under the Web2Case queue

Tags: apex, visualforce, web-to-case

I have created Web2Case using Web-to-case HTML generator form. Also I have created Queue shown below.

The case is getting created successfully using the Web To case HTML form, but its not visible under the `Web2Case` list view & queue. But I can see it in `'My open cases'` list view. Why ? Any help ?

[image]

[image]

***The below I have shown web-to-case settings:***

[image]

And `web-to-case` html form ?

```
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<!--  NOTE: Please add the following <META> element to your page <HEAD>.      -->
<!--  If necessary, please modify the charset parameter to specify the        -->
<!--  character set of your HTML page.                                        -->
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

<META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-type" CONTENT="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<!--  NOTE: Please add the following <FORM> element to your page.             -->
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

<form action="https://www.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToCase?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST">

<input type=hidden name="orgid" value="00D7F0000001I8v">
<input type=hidden name="retURL" value="http://">

<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->
<!--  NOTE: These fields are optional debugging elements. Please uncomment    -->
<!--  these lines if you wish to test in debug mode.                          -->
<!--  <input type="hidden" name="debug" value=1>                              -->
<!--  <input type="hidden" name="debugEmail"                                  -->
                            -->
<!--  ----------------------------------------------------------------------  -->

<label for="name">Contact Name</label><input  id="name" maxlength="80" name="name" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="email">Email</label><input  id="email" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="phone">Phone</label><input  id="phone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="subject">Subject</label><input  id="subject" maxlength="80" name="subject" size="20" type="text" /><br>

<label for="description">Description</label><textarea name="description"></textarea><br>

<label for="priority">Priority</label><select  id="priority" name="priority"><option value="">--None--</option><option value="High">High</option>
<option value="Medium">Medium</option>
<option value="Low">Low</option>
</select><br>

<input type="submit" name="submit">

</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason behind that, you have defined queue and activated Web-to-Case.

> But, you have not configured any assignment rules where web-to-case to be assigned to WebToCase queue.

Refer [Assign Cases](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=cases_assign.htm&language=en&type=0) documentation

It is coming to your name, may be in the Support Settings, Automated Case User is you or Default Case Owner is you.

> **Automated Case User** - The user listed in the Case History related list for automated case changes from:
>
> - Assignment rules
> - Escalation rules
> - On-Demand Email-to-Case
> - Cases logged in the Self-Service portal
>
> **Default Case Owner** - The default owner of a case when assignment rules fail to locate an owner.